# Conditional Excel Sum based on dates range

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, conditional-operator, sumifs

I have got a spreadsheet in where dates are in column B and values are in column E.

Dates are with the format: dd/mm/yy
Values are with the format: XXX,XX€

I am trying to sum cells based on dates but I can't.

I am using the function SUMIFS like this to calculate the values from November:

```
=SUMIFS(E9:E1000;B9:B1000;">="DATE(2014;11;1)&"<="DATE(2014,11,30))
```

I am doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: SOLVED using this: `=SUMIFS(E9:E1000;B9:B1000;">="&DATE(2014;11;1);B9:B1000;"<="&DATE(2014;11;30))`

Comment: Would you please mark my answer accepted? Btw, it's better to set the upper date limit as "<"&DATE(2014,12,1). Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the conditional Sum for specified date range (Nov 2014), correct your syntax as shown in the sample below:

```
=SUMIFS(E9:E1000,B9:B1000,">="&DATE(2014,11,1), B9:B1000,"<"&DATE(2014,12,1))
```

Note: this solution is pertinent to the US date format: mm/dd/yyyy, so you may need to correct it per your case depends on how DATE() function is set on your PC. Also, due to my regional settings it's using a comma-separator, which may be different from the one on you PC (you may need to use semicolon `;`).

Hope this will help. Kind regards,

Comment: Thanks Alex, I think you are in the right direction, but the formula is not working yet. My SUMIFS formula is like this:     `SUMIFS(sum_range;criteria_range1;criteria1...)` - My DATE formula is like this: `DATE(year;month;day)`. I don't know why my excel is not accepting commas and is using semicolons.

Comment: You can try this formula using semicolon (;) separator as per your regional settings. Best regards,

Comment: In Excel 2010, the DATE function is independent of regional settings, it's DATE(year,month,day). The separator does depend on your regional separator though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B9:B1000>=DATE(2014,11,1))*(B9:B1000<=DATE(2014,11,30))*(E9:E1000))
```

Comment: @alexgarciab  use your regional settings for **,** vs **;**